# Binding model Asp.net input type="date"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Update**
I give the model .

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите значение начальной даты")]
public DateTime House1 { get; set; }
```

When I use  `@ Html.EditorFor (model => model.House1)` in View.I have following marking

```
 <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The 
 field  StartDate must be a date." data-val-required="Введите значение"   
 id="StartDate" name="StartDate" type="date" value="29.06.2015">
```

But data  not display in a field.display means not pulled from the model in `input(@ Html.EditorFor (model => model.House1))`

Comment: Do you mean `m => m.House1` or `m => m.StartDate`? And why do you mean it does not display - the html you have shown has a value of "29.06.2015"

Comment: sorry ,I wrote incorrectly,i have the value="29.06.2015"(in inspector),but it is not displayed to the user

Comment: That's because your format for the date is incorrect. You need to show the model property including its data annotation attributes.

Comment: which data annotation attributes?You can show how to write?

Comment: You need to show what you have written (show your model) and I will show you how to correct it

Comment: I show model:)) see above (public DateTime House1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The specification for the HTML-5 datepicker requires that the format be `yyyy-MM-dd`, so you need to modify your property to add the `DisplayFormatAttribute`

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime House1 { get; set; }
```

However keep in mind that there is only limited support for the HTML-5 datepicker and its not even implemented in FireFox. I recommend you consider using a jquery plugin instead